# Materialized View vs View

Tags: oracle, materialized-views

May I know the difference for these two items?

Data in `materialized view` can be refresh but so as `view` when we use select statement. Why not just use `view` instead of `materialized view`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> When you need performance on data that don't need to be up to date to
>   the very second, materialized views are better, but your data will be
>   older than in a standard view.

While creating `Materialized view` Oracle creates two objects, a table where the results are actually materialized and a materialized view that has all the metadata (the query, the attributes, etc.).

But while creating `View` Oracle creates only one object, which has all the metadata(the query, the attributes, etc.)

Comment: My main table contains few millions of data. If I use Materialized View rather than regular view, the data will be duplicated x2?

Comment: @TanSiongZhe I don't know what you mean by x2, but of course it will save datas again unlike view.

Comment: Sorry by x2 I mean times two. Lets say my database currently holds 6 million data, by using MV it will become 12 millions data?

Comment: @TanSiongZhe If the result of your query holds 6 millions data, then yes, it will create a new table which has same name with MV and holds 6 million data.

Answer (score 2):

You use materialized views for performance reasons mainly.

According to the [Oracle docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10500_01/server.920/a96567/repmview.htm):

> A materialized view is a replica of a target master from a single point in time.

A regular view loads data 'on demand' and can 'automatically' change when the underlying data changes.